# Saying 'Yes' while initiating a telephonic or messaging conversation

Tags: conversations, etiquette

Here is a small context.

I am talking to my peers or my other colleagues either on mobile phone or through a messaging system

Me : Hi Ruby

Ruby : Yes

Me : ...

Ruby : ...

Everything seems to be fine. But, that 'Yes' sounds a little authoritative to me. And I feel a little offended about it. Somehow I feel that it is rude.

When the roles are reversed, I say, 'Hi Ruby. Please tell me.' 
I was wondering if that 'Yes' is rude? Am I overthinking?

Answer (score 6):

You're overthinking this. In this context, it is pretty much the same as

> go on.

It is an acknowledgement that they heard you basically. Basically, you first send a greeting to get their attention, they respond that you now have their attention, and then you can go on with what you wanted to say. No more than that.